# Pass argument from PhantomJS command line to page evaluate to change the checkbox state

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to pass an argument from the command line and check or uncheck a check box on my local website. If I substitute the `system.args[4]` in the `returnVars` function with a `true` or `false` it works, but the argument I pass from the command line doesn't affect the check box.

```
var returnVars = function(){
    if (system.args.length > 4) {
        console.log(system.args[4]); // this is getting the correct value from the args
        return system.args[4];
    }
};

page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    } else {
        var  returnable = page.evaluate(function(r,s) {
            return document.getElementById(r).checked = s;
        }, 'returnable', returnVars());

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

I am using the rasterize.js example and replacing the zoom option with my own. I call it with:

```
phantomjs rasterize.js mywebsite.com c:\foo.pdf "letter" false
```

Comment: I am using the rasterize.js example and replacing the zoom option with my own. phantomjs rasterize.js http://mywebsite.com c:\foo.pdf "letter" false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a string `"false"` into `evaluate` and setting the `checked` property to this string. The string is then evaluated to `true`, because `!!"false" === true` and `!!"true" === true`. If hope you see the problem now.

This is easy to fix. Since you're passing JavaScript code (`false`) as a string, you need to execute the string so that it is JavaScript code again:

```
document.getElementById(r).checked = eval(s);
```

`eval` is usually evil, but since this is your local script, there is nothing you can break security-wise.

Comment: Thanks. I spent half the morning on this.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) is rather helpful in this matter.